# AngularJS - convert file object to image object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to convert file object to image object?
I need width and height from file (which is an image), here is my code:

**view:**

```
<button id="image_file" class="md-button md-raised md-primary"
type="file" ngf-select="uploadFile($file)">
SELECT FILE
</button>

<md-input-container>
<div class="raised">
<input id="image_file_name" type="text" ng-model="vm.file.name"></input>
 </div>    
</md-input-container>
```

**controller:**

```
app.controller('imageController', function($scope, fileService) {

$scope.vm = {};

$('.intro').show(1000);

$scope.uploadFile = function(file) {
$scope.vm.file = "";
$scope.vm.file = file;    //<---- for example here, how it should be done?
   fileService.uploadFile($scope);
}
```

**service:**

```
angular.module('app')
.service('fileService', function ($http,  validationService) {

      this.uploadFile = function ($scope){
        if (validationService.isFileValidate($scope)) {
            $scope.vm.acceptableFormat = true;
        }  else {
            $scope.vm.acceptableFormat = false;
        }

    };

     });
```

Comment: How is the file selected  ? I mean where is `<input type= 'file' />` ?

Comment: @Searching it's under button on the top of 'view' code, I'm using ng-file-upload here

Comment: still not working is it ?

Comment: Now it's fine, but file.$ngfWidth was undefined until I put directive 'ng-height-min=1' in input, now I can get width and weight from file, thanks :)

Comment: Great.. This might sound dum.. but was there a `file` selected when you did that ? i mean was `file != undefined` in `$scope.uploadFile` ?

Comment: Nope, file object was initialized and filled, It looks like $ngWidth appears, but only if we force it to appear by some directives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library already seems to give most of what you require. To read width and height properties of the file/image .

```
 //Add accept option to filter only images
 <button id="image_file" class="md-button md-raised md-primary"
 type="file" accept="image/*" ngf-select="uploadFile($file)">
 SELECT FILE
 </button>
```

Controller

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(file) {
 $scope.vm.file = "";
 $scope.vm.file = file;    
// show all file properties
 console.log(file); // Show available properties
 console.log(file.$ngfWidth +','+ file.$ngfHeight) // Your width and height
 fileService.uploadFile($scope);
```

}

You should probably check out it's [Features](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#features).